# MySQL names resolution order in query

Tags: mysql

I switched in my app from SQLite to MySQL

I have nested queries (the number is variable so it's useful to me keeping always same names) like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as datetime FROM (
    SELECT datetime FROM (...) AS T
) AS T GROUP BY datetime
```

in SQLIte `GROUP BY datetime` is evaulated on formatted date so the grouping takes place while in MySQL plain passed `datetime` is used so I have no grouping.

To better explain this works in MySQL but brakes my cycle having to rename columns and/or tables `AS` at each loop:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as new_datetime FROM (
    SELECT datetime FROM (...) AS T
) AS T GROUP BY new_datetime
```

So, is there a way to make MySQL group the `datetime` I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by the formatted datetime, pass that into the group by clause:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

This will avoid multiple rows on different minutes/seconds.

To avoid calling DATE_FORMAT twice, you can use something like:

`SELECT @dtm := DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as datetime FROM tablename AS T GROUP BY @dtm`

Comment: isn't this supposed to double the DATE_FORMAT calls??? (this is why I didn't use it from the start).

Comment: Are you trying to avoid calling date_format twice, or aliasing columns?  I guess I'm confused.

Comment: You should be able to use something like this:

`SELECT @dtm := DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as datetime FROM tablename AS T GROUP BY @dtm`

Comment: I get the first (grouping) hour twice then all others just once (???) like `2010-09-09 08:00:00, 2010-09-09 08:00:00, 2010-09-09 09:00:00, 2010-09-09 10:00:00, 2010-09-09 11:00:00 ...` can you place a link on this syntax documentation? Thanks

Comment: [Reading here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html): "In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list does not work as expected." So I guess that's why I get weird results...

Comment: Yeah...you may not be able to avoid it, the link to the variable documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html

Comment: you can still use the group by clause I put as my first solution, aside from being ugly, it should work just fine.  The operation cost should be negligible unless you have a huge data set.

Comment: I have a huge data set, sob... and need to optimize wherever I can. I ended using second form in my question and making coding more complex. Of course it's not a solution to my question since it was how to avoid it... ^^